# Dimensionality reduction on repeated measures: PCA? MFA? (FactoMineR)

Tags: r, dimensionality-reduction, longitudinal, factominer

I have a repeated measures sample, where each participant was asked to complete a sleep survey over the course of 5 years (baseline though year 4 of follow-up). Each survey item is fairly correlated (e.g. when you go to bed correlates with your duration of sleep) and so we are interested in taking a PCA-like approach and use loadings on each PC to create a time-varying composite score (e.g. a composite score based on these hypothetical "PC" "loadings" for each time point). Then we want to take each participant's time-varying composite measure in a mixed model to predict our longitudinal outcome of interest.

We initially performed PCA on all of the data (all participants and across all time points), but there are a few assumptions here. But, upon further reflection, I started to question if the PCA is able to distinguish between participant- or time-based variability. And so, I am looking for a way to perform a similar dimensionality reduction approach on a repeated measures sample.

Based on some previous stack questions I found, it looks like MFA might be a good option. But all of the examples I see online don't include longitudinal analysis.

**1. Does MFA seem like the correct approach?**

**2. And if so, is the following code correct for `library(FactoMineR)`**

Below is a sample dataset illustrating the structure and code I think I'd run:

```
library(FactoMineR)
set.seed(123)
ex_dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:4, each=4),
                     visit = rep(c("baseline", "y1", "y2", "y3"), 4),
                     var1 = rnorm(16),
                     var2 = rnorm(16)^2,
                     var3 = log(rnorm(16, mean=3, sd=1)))
dat <- ex_dat %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, 
                                 names_from = visit,
                                 values_from = c("var1", "var2", "var3")) %>% data.frame()
> dat
  ID var1_baseline    var1_y1    var1_y2     var1_y3 var2_baseline    var2_y1   var2_y2    var2_y3 var3_baseline   var3_y1   var3_y2   var3_y3
1  1    -0.5604756 -0.2301775  1.5587083  0.07050839     0.2478551 3.86758304 0.4919001 0.22353172     1.3597259 1.3553540 1.3406642 1.3052579
2  2     0.1292877  1.7150650  0.4609162 -1.26506123     1.1402475 0.04751306 1.0526851 0.53128242     1.2680506 1.0777591 0.9910409 0.9629945
3  3    -0.6868529 -0.4456620  1.2240818  0.35981383     0.3906741 2.84493432 0.7018871 0.02352331     0.8352078 1.0267878 0.5507789 1.6426707
4  4     0.4007715  0.1106827 -0.5558411  1.78691314     1.2953557 1.57205186 0.1818717 0.08706718     1.4369784 0.6296169 0.9544013 0.9295404
```

So, for each participant I have multiple measurements of variables 1 through 3.

My hunch, based on the MFA manual would be to run code like this to perform MFA. This, I'm guessing, assumes that all `var1`, `var2`, `var3` variables are in their own "group".

```
# MFA Analysis
res_MFA <- MFA(dat[, -1], group=rep(4, 3), type=rep("s", 3))
```

And lastly... does `res_MFA$ind$coord` give me the equivalent of a "loading" for each dimension?

Comment: Would using a library that can construct a composite PCA score be helpful? You can make an elbow plot to check how much variance is captured by the PCs and then proceed.

Comment: @DeathMetal thanks for your comment! I've performed PCA on the datasets in long form (throwing all participants and all time points into the PCA) and have looked at the elbow -- there's not a huge kink, unfortunately. But, my main concern is if I should be worried about the fact that there are multiple rows for each participant). I'm definitely interested in a composite PCA score, but just want to make sure that the variability that accurately accounting for the sort of pseudo-replication problem I have here.

Comment: I see; we need a library that constructs a composite PCA for replicates. There's an R library that constructs composite PCA score. Not sure if allows replicates part of the problem you're facing. Second, for the kink in the PCs, I think you can use the PCs until the variance decay gets saturated. No harm in capturing N number of PCs as long as variance is captured.

Comment: @DeathMetal good point! :) Thank you for your input!